# Generate subsequences in R

Tags: r

I have a df which is 67200 obs long, with 5 vars. I would like to create a list of subsequences from one var, each of equal length (600 obs). I would like the sequence to be iterative so that I can identify rolling sequences i.e. seq1 = 0:600, seq2 = 1:601, seq3 = 2:602, and so on. I will then sum the data from each subsequence to identify the sequence with the highest total.

I understand how to make a basic sequence using `seq`, however after reading around SO and other sites, I can only find info on how to identify specific sequences. Any help with ideas on ways to create said subsequences would be great.

Sample Data:

```
Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5
0.00  0.31  0.32  0.00  0.01
0.10  0.46  0.46  0.13  0.01
0.20  0.46  0.47  0.14  0.02
0.30  0.40  0.21  0.14  0.02
0.40  0.38  0.11  0.20  0.03
0.50  0.38  0.07  0.25  0.04
```

Expected Output:
List of x each subsequnce

Comment: Sample data and expected output? (Something smaller than 67K rows, pls :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question I think you can achieve your expected output with `lapply` and `seq` :

```
x <- 600
n <- 0:(nrow(df) - 600)
lapply(n, function(i) seq(i, i+x))
```

However, reading the description it seems you are trying to perform rolling calculation and the above is not the best approach to do this. Look into `zoo` library it has functions like `rollsum`, `rollmean` or a general `rollapply` which will have better way to do this.

Comment: `rollapply` function works a treat - `output <- rollapply(df$var1, FUN = sum, width = 600)`